# Semantic UI Dropdown multiple select close not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I am working on multiple selection dropdown in semantic ui and have got most of it working except closing out of items after you've selected them.

I have replicated the example they give in the documentation in a jsfiddle and still having the same problem.

I have also tried putting a 'close' parameter in the dropdown function.

http://jsfiddle.net/mpenovich1/qYp8L/28/

```
$('#multi-select').dropdown();
```

https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the item delete button (✖) and the dropdown button (▼) working, you have to use a more recent version of jQuery than 1.7.1, apparently. Here is **[a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/0vLzpocg/3/)** that works with version 1.9.1 (specified in the Javascript pane). According to my tests, it also works with jQuery 2.2.4 and 3.2.1.

The code itself has not changed:

```
$('#multi-select').dropdown();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was actually referring to the multiple elements added from the list with the 'x'. For example if I were to choose Alabama and Alaska, then decided to remove Alabama.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I updated my answer.

Comment: Duh. That was it. Thank you!